# How to remove punctuation from time duration with Moment.js duration format

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs, duration

I am using [moment duration format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) to calculate total time duration it works fine, however when time duration goes in 4 digits it adds comma in hours (consider money format).

What I have:

```
moment.duration(33869100, 'seconds').format('hh:mm:ss', {trim: false})
```

Out put: **9,408:05:00** ---> note the hours have comma I need this format **9408:05:00** without comma no money format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply [disable grouping](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#usegrouping) like so

```
moment.duration(33869100, 'seconds').format('hh:mm:ss', {trim: false, useGrouping: false})
```

Comment: Weird how I missed that :(

Comment: @KamranKhatti it's understandable to miss it, I don't know anyone who reads every single bit of the documentation, but before asking a question on SO please just give it a quick read through :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure Moment can change that for you but you can, simply do a replace:

```
/* using regex, .replace(/,/g, '') replaces all commas in case you run into large numbers */
moment.duration(33869100, 'seconds').format('hh:mm:ss', {trim: false}).replace(/,/g, '')
```

[Here's a fiddle showing it working](http://jsfiddle.net/rafdjcb3/)

**EDIT: refer to answer from @George, Moment can do this for you**